# Ember.js: How to observe when a value in an input field changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to create a simple HTML input text field in my Ember.js app. The value to this particular input box is not bound to any specific model. When the input text box blurs or loses focus, I need to be able to run some JavaScript. In my template, I have this so far:

```
{{input valueBinding="pitcherSalary" placeholder=0}}
```

I tried observing the value of `pitcherSalary` by doing the following in the controller without any luck:

```
MyApp.OptimalController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 pitcherSalaryObserver: function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log("changing....");
  }.observes('pitcherSalary'), 
});
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say it isn't backed by some model, yet your controller is saying it's backed by some model.  It's likely you're confusing Ember, it wants to save to the model, which should be backing the controller, but it finds no model.  ObjectController proxies properties to/from the controller to the model, and when it has no model, it yells about misuse.

### Bad: ObjectController without a model

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/niyawido/3/edit

### Good: ObjectController with a model

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/niyawido/4/edit

### Good: Controller without a model

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/niyawido/2/edit

Comment: This really helped me understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much for the jsbins.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a plain old "value" in your input tag? Here's a fat example that uses the style of observable you want using the prototype extension: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zuxuli/2/edit

My inputs:

```
{{input type=number value=amount placeholder="Billed Amount"}}
{{input type="checkbox" checked=roundTip}} //"checked" is a kind of value attrib
```

My observables:

```
observeStuff: function () {
  console.log("blah!!!");
}.observes('roundTip'),

observeStuff2: function () {
  console.log("crap!!!");
}.observes('amount'),
```

Hope this helps.

edit: see [Ember.Observable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html) and [#addObserver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectController.html#method_addObserver) for better documentation.

Comment: valueBinding='amount' works as well (though, I prefer value=amount), http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yeletulu/1/edit.  Upvote for observeShit naming schema.

Comment: Do you have to put the observeStuff: method into an `Ember.Object`? can it not go in the controller?